# How to enqueue a job in rq from redis

Tags: python, redis, scheduled-tasks

I have to fetch functions and time when it execute from mysql and then save this thing into redis.Now from redis I have to execute functions at prescribed time.I want to use rq as scheduler but I am not able to find out the model in which I should save  imported data into redis.
I am totally new in python and redis

Answer (score 1):

If you install redis there is a file (for me it was the ~/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rq/queue.py which in turn calls job.py) that clearly states the enqueue and enqueue_call functions:

```
def enqueue_call(self, func, args=None, kwargs=None,
                 timeout=None, result_ttl=None, description=None,
                 depends_on=None):
    """Creates a job to represent the delayed function call and enqueues it.

    It is much like `.enqueue()`, except that it takes the function's args
    and kwargs as explicit arguments.  Any kwargs passed to this function
    contain options for RQ itself.
    etc...."""

def enqueue(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
    """Creates a job to represent the delayed function call and enqueues it.

    Expects the function to call, along with the arguments and keyword
    arguments.
    etc...."""
```